# id, string or integer was expected with eval()

Tags: javascript

I get a strange error in IE.. but no problems in both FF and chrome

when I alert the variable I get this:

```
json_post('delete_accounting', 'json.action.php?action=delete_accounting', 'id=682', 'rtn_accounting', {tr_id:'tr_acc682', enc_id:374, delete:1});
```

but when I want to eval() the sting I get this error (the error is translated from danish, so I don't know how it is put in english?)

```
id, string or integer was expected
```

EDIT:

```
var xmlhttp = {};
function json_post(request_var, response, get_str, callback_function, callback_var)
{
    request_var += Math.floor(Math.random()*999).toString();

    CNSTR.mouseLoader.cnstr();

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp[request_var] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) xmlhttp[request_var] = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

    xmlhttp[request_var].open('POST', response, true);
    xmlhttp[request_var].setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp[request_var].onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp[request_var].readyState == 4)
        {
            CNSTR.mouseLoader.dstr();

            if(callback_function) eval(callback_function+'('+xmlhttp[request_var].responseText+(callback_var ? ', callback_var':'')+')');
        }
    }
    xmlhttp[request_var].send(get_str);
}
```

I'm quite sure that the error occurs in the eval() because when I run the sting as real code there are no problems..

like this:

```
json_post('delete_accounting', 'json.action.php?action=delete_accounting', 'id=682', 'rtn_accounting', {tr_id:'tr_acc682', enc_id:374, delete:1});
```

I have also tried to escape everything in the callback function rtn_accounting(), and still the same error in the same line with the eval()

Comment: Can you show the exact code you are using? What does `json_post` do?

Comment: Alternatively, use alerts (or a debugging tool...) to check that json_post is running.

Comment: the question is edited.. I don't know how to check if the json_post is running in IE... the only tool I know of is firebug in FF, but thats not where my problem is

Comment: I have now put an alert in the top of the function json_post() but nothing is alerted.. so I don't think the error is in that function

Comment: is there any reason to use `eval`? You could invoce the function given by `callback_function` directly!

Comment: because it is some quite old code.. it would take a lot of work to change it.. but i solved the problem by adding some quotes in the object in the last parameter... json_post('delete_accounting', 'json.action.php?action=delete_accounting', 'id=682', 'rtn_accounting', {'tr_id':'tr_acc682', 'enc_id':374, 'delete':1});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding quotes in the object in the last parameter is works

```
json_post('delete_accounting', 'json.action.php?action=delete_accounting', 'id=682', 'rtn_accounting', {'tr_id':'tr_acc682', 'enc_id':374, 'delete':1});
```

Comment: `delete` is a key word. The behavior is ECMA3 compliant. In ECMA5 this is fixed.

Comment: ahh.. ok.. then it gives more sense